# How to extract real name, first name, lastname, and create nickname from name that have acronyms, aristocratic title, academic titles/degrees

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to extract name, firstname, lastname, create nickname/firstname, and nickname/lastname from name list that have acronyms, aristocratic title, academic titles/degrees, nickname inside parentheses or after slash-backslash in libreoffice calc using regex function. This is the expected result

[image: expected result]

The rules are:

1. **Expected Name**: remove nickname inside parentheses or after slash-backslash if exist, job titles, academic titles and degrees except for (R) or (R.), (Ra) or (Ra.), and one alphabet with(out) `dot` in the name ex: (A.) (A), (M.), and name acronym with(out) `dot` ex: (Muh.), (Moh), etc
2. **Firstname**: (from **expected name**) extract first name including `dot` in acronym ex: (R.), (Ra.), (Muh.) and one alphabet with(out) `dot` in the name ex: (A.) (A), (M.)
3. **Lastname**: (from **expected name**) extract last name including `dot`
4. **Nickname-fname**: from Input Name, extract nickname inside parentheses or after slash-backslash if exist. If not exist, extract first name that is not: one char, acronym with(out) `dot`, "I Gede", "I Gusti", "I Made", "Ni Luh Putu", or "Ni Putu". If not exist, use next word in name even it's last word. If the name consist only one word, extract it even only one character
5. **Nickname-lname**: from Input Name, extract nickname inside parentheses or after slash-backslash if exist. If not exist, extract last name that is not: one char or acronym with(out) `dot`. If not exist, extract prev word in name even it's first word. If the name consist only one word, extract it even only one character

I tried the following:

```
=REGEX($A2,"\(.*?\)|\([^)]*\)|\\[^\\]*$|\/[^\/]*$|,.*","")
```

to extract real name. It remove nickname inside parentheses or after slash-backslash with(out) `space` like

```
( Nita ) in Yunita ( Nita )
( Nita ) in Yunita( Nita )
(Nita) in  Yunita (Nita)
(Nita) in  Yunita(Nita)
( Nita) in  Yunita ( Nita)
( Nita) in  Yunita( Nita)
(Nita ) in  Yunita (Nita )
(Nita ) in  Yunita(Nita ))
\Nita in  Yunita\Nita
\ Nita in  Yunita\ Nita
\Nita in  Yunita \Nita
 \ Nita in  Yunita \ Nita
...
and so on
```

it also remove academic degrees like `Ph.D.` but it **failed** on `Ra. Ayu S. Ph.D.` (because there is no `comma` after `S.`). It **failed** on `Prof.` and `Dr.`. I want to keep `Ra.`.

```
=REGEX($A23,"(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))([\w.]+)")
```

to extract first name but **failed** on `Moh.Ali` (yes, without `space` after `dot`).

```
=REGEX($A23,"\b(?<last>[\w\[.\]\\]+)$")
```

to extract last name but also **failed** on `Moh.Ali`.

```
=REGEX($A2,"(\(.*?\)|\([^)]*\)|\\[^\\]*$|\/[^\/]*$)|(\b(?<first>\w+)$)")
```

to create nickname extracted from given nickname inside parentheses or after slash or backslash. If nickname not exist create one from `first name` that is not: one char, acronym with(out) `dot`, "I Gede", "I Gusti", "I Made", "Ni Luh Putu", or "Ni Putu". If the first name not meet condition, use `next word` in name even it's `last word`. If still not meet condition, use name that consist only one word, extract it even only one character. The `regex` **failed** in most case.

```
=REGEX($A2,"(\(.*?\)|\([^)]*\)|\\[^\\]*$|\/[^\/]*$)|(\b(?<last>\w+)$)")
```

to create nickname extracted from given nickname inside parentheses or after slash or backslash. If nickname not exist create one from `last name` that is not: one char, acronym with(out) `dot`. If the `last name` not meet condition, use `prev word` in name even it's `first word`. If still not meet condition, use name that consist only one word, extract it even only one character. It **failed** in most case too.

This is the result of the regex:

[image: trial result]

But I'm new to regex and stuck. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

The parsing rules are rather elaborate, especially for nicknames, so
I suggest using a multi-step process involving 2 helper columns and
the non-advanced
(POSIX [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)
plus `\b`) features of the available
[ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html)
regular expressions combined with a few spreadsheet formulas.

If you copy the formulas listed and commented below to columns B
through H in your spreadsheet you should find that
*conditional formatting* highlights a total of 5 cells, all nicknames:
1 for `Jasmine`, 2 for `Imah`, and 2 for `Nur.`. For the first 3
the expected result contradicts the nickname rules; removing
the dot in `Nur.` is left as an exercise.

I used the input as it is but in cases like this pre-processing is
the key to avoid complex or special-case regexes, e.g. insert a blank
in names like `M.Ali`, or prefix a comma to comma-less `Ph.D.`.

Aside: When you post source data as an image rather than plaintext
what's the likelihood of someone OCR'ing the image and editing the
text?

---

*Step 1*

Add auxiliary column `AuxSplit` separating the input string into its
3 main groups -- name, titles, nickname (last 2 optional) -- and
joining them with `@`. **NB**: `@` is used for this reply but it
must be a non-meta character not appearing in any input string.

```
REGEX(A22;"(.*?)( *(Ph\.D\.)?|(,[^\\/(]*?))?( *[\\/(].*)? *$";"$1@$2@$5")
```

where

- `$` anchors regex to end of string
- `$5` is the captured optional nickname (incl. any delimiters and blanks)
- `$2` the optional suffixed titles (incl. any comma and blanks);
  note that the comma-less `Ph.D` is special-cased
- `$1` the name (incl. any leading blanks)

Sample content: `Jasmine Fianna@, B.A., M.A.@/Jasmine`

---

*Step 2*

Add auxiliary column `AuxNick` extracting an explicit nickname (if any)
from 3rd main group (after last `@`) in `AuxSplit`.

```
REGEX(G22;".*@[\\/( ]*([^ )]*)[ )]*$";"$1")
```

Capturing string after `\` or `/` or between `()`, trimming off blanks.

Sample content `Agus`.

---

*Step 3*

Extract `ExpectedName` from 1st group (up to first `@`) in `AuxSplit`
stripping off any prefixed titles.

```
REGEX(G22;"^((Prof|Dr)\.[ ]*)?([^@]*).*";"$3")
```

Note that these titles are special-cased as they have the same form
as an abbreviated name.

Sample content: `Q. Ranita El`

---

*Step 4*

From `ExpectedName` extract `Firstname`,

```
REGEX(B22;"^(Ra?\.?|[^.]+\.|[^ ]+)")
```

stripping off R/R./Ra/Ra. and blanks from start of string,

and `Lastname`

```
REGEX(B22;"[^ .]*[^ ]$")
```

extracting the last character sequence after blank/dot;
any trailing blanks were removed in step 1.

*Note*: with `M.Ali` as `M. Ali` simplify `Lastname` formula to
`REGEX(B22;"[^ ]+$")`

---

*Step 5*

Extract `Lastnick` from `AuxNick`, `LastName`, or `ExpectedName`

```
IF(LEN(H22);H22;IF(ISNA(REGEX(D22;"\b([^ ]+\.|[^ .])$"));D22;REGEX(B22;".*?([^ ]+)[ ]+([^ ]*\.|[^.])$";"$1")))
```

- `IF(LEN(H22);H22` : use explicit nickname if present
- `;IF(ISNA(REGEX(D22;"…";D22` : else use `Lastname` unless abbrev. or 1-char.
- `;REGEX(B22;"…";"$1")))` : else use previous word in name, exploiting the
  fact that an unmatched replacement returns the entire string

and `Firstnick` from `AuxNick`, `FirstName`, or `ExpectedName`

```
IF(LEN(H22);H22;IF(ISNA(REGEX(B22;"^([^ ]+\.|[^ ]\b|I (Gede|Gusti|Made)\b|Ni (Luh )?Putu\b)"));C22;REGEX(B22;"^(I (Gede|Gusti|Made)\b|Ni (Luh )?Putu\b|.*?)[ .]\b([^ ]+).*";"$4")))
```

- `IF(LEN(H22);H22` : use explicit nickname if present
- `;IF(ISNA(REGEX(B22;"…";C22` : else use `FirstName` unless abbrev. / 1-char. / special case
- `;REGEX(B22;"…";"$4")))` : else use next word in name, exploiting the
  fact that an unmatched replacement returns the entire string

**TODO**: remove trailing dot from `Nur.`

Recall the (LibreOffice 6.2+) `REGEX` syntax:

> *Syntax*: REGEX( Text ; Expression [ ; [ Replacement ] [ ; Flags|Occurrence ] ] )

> *Expression*: A text representing the regular expression, using 
> [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) 
> regular expressions. If there is no match and Replacement is not 
> given, #N/A is returned.
>
> *Replacement*: Optional. The replacement text and references to capture
> groups. If there is no match, Text is returned unmodified.